# Role of Mass in Newtonian Gravity

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass

1. Does the mass of a body *not* influence the effect of gravity on a body in the vacuum?
2. If so then why does the Newton's second law  $F=mg$ suggests that the mass effects at the force of gravity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say that the mass of a body doesn't play a role in the effect of gravity on a body in the vacuum means that it doesn't play a role in what acceleration the body will experience. The very existence of a quantity like the gravitational acceleration $g$ inherits this fact that there is a unique acceleration $g$ with which every object (regardless of their mass) will respond to the gravitational field present at that point. But, as you have noticed, the force of gravity $F=mg$ does depend on the mass of the body. A rather clearer way to see this is following: Let's say there is a gravitational field $\vec{E_g}$ then the force on this body is $\vec{F}=m\vec{E_g}$. This force, clearly, depends on the body of the mass. But, the acceleration $\vec{a}=\dfrac{\vec{F}}{m}=\dfrac{m\vec{E_g}}{m}=\vec{E_g}$ is independent of the mass. And, this acceleration is precisely equal to the gravitational field at that point. This is the very reason we use gravitational acceleration to represent the gravitational field at any point. It is not obvious that we can always do this. For example, in the case of the electric forces, the acceleration $\vec{a}=\dfrac{\vec{F}}{m}=\dfrac{q\vec{E_e}}{m}$ does depend on the mass of the object (unlike the gravitational case) and thus, we can't use the acceleration caused due to the electric field to represent the electric field - because there isn't a one-one onto relation between then unless the mass and charge of the test particle is specified.

Comment: so if we throw apple and paper in vacuum what will fall first?

Comment: It depends on the initial velocity and initial position, of course. If the initial velocities and initial positions of the both of them are same then they will fall simultaneously.

Comment: so the law f=ma is true on air only but in vacuum is fault ?

Comment: I don't understand how $F=ma$ is false in the vacuum. Maybe you can look up Feynman lectures (freely available here: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_toc.html) on how Newtonian mechanics works and what it means.

Comment: if we assume the paper is 1 g and apple 1kg so the force of gravity of apple =1000*9.81 and the force of gravity of paper =1*9.81 so the apple must fall before paper but in vacuum is false

Comment: do you agree with my comment

Comment: @AhmedEmad They both accelerate at $9.81 \frac m{s^2}$, therefore they fall at the same time.  More force doesn't always accelerate things faster if they have different masses.